# What is a continent?

Tags: terminology, civilization-2

In Civilization 2, two wonders of the world refer in their rules to "continents." Hoover Dam:

> Provides Hydro power to every city on every **continent**.

And J. S. Bach's Cathedral:

> Decreases unhappy citizens on same **continent** by 2 per city.

It's not clear to me what a continent is. It's been a long time since I last read the manual, but I don't think it was explained there either.

Is a continent a contiguous region of land? Let's say I am playing the world map. Is Europe+Asia+Africa single continent? Is Great Britain a separate continent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Any city which can be reached by land is considered "on the same continent". If you built Bach's Cathedral in Paris, it would affect cities in Asia but would not affect London.